# Most simple tree data structure in Python, that can be easily traversed in both directions

Tags: python, data-structures

I would need the simplest possible implementation for a data structure, that can be traversed in both parent->children and children->parent direction; so ideally the child should hold a reference to the parent as well.

Was thinking about a dictionary, where the children would simply hold a reference to their parent, similar to this:

```
# define the root node
a = {'name': 'trunk', 'value': 0, 'parent': None, 'children': []}
# add child
a['children'].append({'name': 'branch-1', 'value': 1,
                      'parent': a, 'children': []})
# and so on...
```

Is this safe to do? (Circular reference might impact garbage collection?) Does it make sense to do this? What would be simpler?

Comment: One could argue that simple can mean little amount of code to maintain or traverse the structure. Another argument could consider simple to be the amount of space usage being less. Another interpretation would consider time complexity of the operations to define simple.

Comment: Well you are right, it is not always easy to define that objectively. What I mean by it I guess is that it has the least possible moving parts and it is as close to the basic data constructs in the language as possible. Obviously without being too hard to use too...

Comment: If the children only reference the parent, it would be hard to move from parent to child. A few questions. Do you have a unique value at each node?
Are you familiar with creating classes?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with classes and I know how I could implement something like this with classes and weak references, was really looking for a more "lightweight" solution. The parent has a list of its children, what would be a better solution to that?

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode and sorry, forgot this: let's assume the nodes are unique.

Comment: btw earlier I meant it'd be hard to traverse from child to parent if you only keep a list of children in parent. Will there be multiple branches or a single flow? Also if you share how you intend to use the nodes I can probably help you work out more specific methods you'd want to include. Obviously more functionality makes it less 'simple'

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode Thank you, I guess I made the mistake of not being more specific here. My needs are very minimalistic, being: build out the tree from root and occasionally traverse a few levels up from a node to read stuff. So no updates, no deletes, only build the tree then move and read. Actually I am planning to wrap `ElementTree` objects this way (I can only use the stdlib version. No parent refs :(  ) to have the ability to peek a few parents up to cross check dependencies. With that said I still liked your answer, maybe was trying too hard to avoid classes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make a Node class.

The basic structure would look something like this, though honestly you could probably do it with dicts too. Just personally feel classes are cleaner looking.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None # Single object
        self.child = []  # Array of objects
        self.name = None
        self.data = None
```

The rest depends on your needs. Some functions you may want built into your class (or if you use hashes, build out as methods in your script)

- Update: which takes a specific node and updates its values/name/what 
  have you
- Delete: which takes a specific node and removes it from the tree. If
  you do this make sure to connect the deleted nodes children to the
  deleted nodes parent.
- Insert: which takes a specific point in the tree and adds a new node
  into it. This should update the parent and children around the node.
- Update children: appends children to node.child array. Should be
  called from update parent as the two processes are self referential.
- Update parent: Deletes self from parent.child array. Adds self to
  new_parent.child array.

If you want to easily reference specific parts of a node, you can make a hash_map as a sort of table of contents

```
node_tree_map = {}
node_tree_map[node.name] = node 
# node_tree_map['name'] would allow you quick access to bob's
# parent/children/value 
# just by knowing the name but without having to traverse 
# the whole tree to find it
```

The above will allow you to easily dive into specific nodes if necessary.

Btw, removing a node from being referenced in the tree or hash map would make garbage collection a non issue.

Comment: I take this as the answer, liked that you started with the minimalistic class, then taking educative approach to lay out options. The "hybrid" solution to look up specific nodes is also a nice touch, I might use it in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

A simple Tree (Node) class, that can be traversed both ways:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, data, children=None, parent=None):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children or []
        self.parent = parent

    def add_child(self, data):
        new_child = Tree(data, parent=self)
        self.children.append(new_child)
        return new_child

    def is_root(self):
        return self.parent is None

    def is_leaf(self):
        return not self.children

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_leaf():
            return str(self.data)
        return '{data} [{children}]'.format(data=self.data, children=', '.join(map(str, self.children)))

> t = Tree('foo')
> bar = t.add_child('bar')
> baz = t.add_child('baz')
> print(t)
'foo [bar, baz]'

> print(bar.parent)
'foo [bar, baz]'
```